# Get all custom UICell properties in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, properties, custom-cell

I created a UITableView with custom cells. I got 5 cells with a `PickerView` inside and another one with an `UITextField`.

I'd like to get all the property values of these cells when I click on a button (meaning the `UITextField text` and the `UIPickView` values).

So far I tried the `self.mainTableView visibleCells`, I do obtain some infos but nothing about the property values of my cells.

Is there any way to get all values put into my cells ?

Answer (score 0):

Using a double for you can have every cell:

```
for (int i = 0; i < [self.mainTableView numberOfSections]; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < [self.mainTableView numberOfRowsInSection:i]; j++){
        UITableViewCell *cell = [self.mainTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:j inSection:i]]
        // Get your value
    }
}
```

But you have to check the "reuse settings" of the tableView.

Comment: Thank you for this but I don't understand what you mean by the "reuse settings". Is this about the way I create my cell ?

Comment: Yes, if you use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` to create the cell, you will lose the values once the cell disappear.

Answer (score 0):

You should create connection between cells and class that performs actions(on button tap).
This could be some delegate or block that informs about changing the value of textFields or UIPicker.

```
@protocol SomeCustomCellDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)onValueChanged:(NSString *)value atCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell

@end
```

Loop directly through cells is bad idea cause it's not safe.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm using the same class for my 6 cells, guess if I do it your way I have to set the cell.tag ?

Comment: No, you could get NSIndexPath of cell by using tableView's [indexPathForCell:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/indexPathForCell:) method.